# Selenium via a grid setup takes much longer than running the webdriver locally

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

Running with local webdriver my test suite completes in 2.7hrs, Running a remote webdriver with hub/node setup the tests take 21.4hrs.

I'm looking for ways to pin point what is actually the cause of this significant overhead.

**Notes so far**

- The build machine and all the hub and node machines are all VMs with the exact same specifications.
- The Node and Hub hangs (40-50s which is fortunately less than the 60s timeout) on a very small number of find element calls.

[image: Hub and Node performance on typical test unit]

- Idle is not because my C# not calling the webdriver. It is waiting on the hub's response and the node does log that `INFO - Executing: [find element: By.selector:...`, the selector is a CSS selector.
- Behaviour is the same for the IE driver.
- For most of the `FindElement` calls I can replace them with a `ExecuteScript` call and use jQuery instead. In these cases I no longer hang/idle for 40-50s. Yet I can't replace all calls this way.

Comment: do u restart the hub and node frequently

Comment: VM performance, 9/10 times, is limited by disk IO! I would check that first.

Comment: Just used resource monitor, disk I/O isn't an issue on the hub/node machines. Neither is CPU, memory or network. Nothing is saturating and becoming a bottleneck. I am spotting a weird behaviour where a few (and I mean only a few) "find element by css selector" calls just hang for 40-50 seconds. I'll test on local to see if the same happens.

Comment: @Rishi restart the java yes, restart the machines no.

Comment: please restart your nodes and let me know if there is any improvement in the performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to implicit waits being set, in the remote web driver initialisation (by another developer). Remove it and the behaviour returns to what I was wanting.